# MongoDB Aggregate and Update Exercise

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I was practicing on mongoDB. Currently, this is my first attempt on NoSql  databases. I have a generic movie collection(video_movieDetails). In it, there are `"_id"` `"title"` `"year"` `"director"` `"writers"` `"countries"`. I am able to write queries like "Construct a query and return all movies where Ian McKellen or Elijah Woods played in, but not both in movies.

`db.video_movieDetails.find({$or:[{$and:[{"actors":"Ian McKellen"},{"actors":{$ne:"Elijah Woods"}}]},{$and:[{"actors":"Elijah Woods"},{"actors":{$ne:"Ian McKellen"}}]}]})`

Now I am trying to achieve,

1. Titles and number of movies of each movie director.(For aggregation)
2. Updating a director's name from "Tim Burton" to "T. Burton". Eventually, all of the names should be updated on corresponding movie. (Updating)

How may I achieve this two queries? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this setup:

```
db.foo.insert([
      {"_id": 0,title: "Movie A",  year: 2010, director: "D1", actors: ["A1","A2"] }
      ,{"_id": 1,title: "Movie B",  year: 2010, director: "D1", actors: ["A1","A5","A6"]}
      ,{"_id": 2,title: "Movie C",  year: 2010, director: "D2", actors: ["A4"]}
      ,{"_id": 3,title: "Movie D",  year: 2012, director: "D3", actors: ["A7"]}
      ,{"_id": 4,title: "Movie E",  year: 2015, director: "D3", actors: ["A7"]}
               ]);

c = db.foo.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: "$director", movies: {$push: "$title"}, count: {$sum:1}}}
                      ]);
show(c, true);

//  For update(), note the option multi:true.  Without it, mongodb will update ONLY the
//  first doc matching the query criteria, not ALL the docs.
rc = db.foo.update({director: "D3"},{$set: {"director":"T. Burton"}},{multi:true});
printjson(rc);

c = db.foo.aggregate([]);
show(c, true);
```

you get this:

```
{ "_id" : "D1", "movies" : [ "Movie A", "Movie B" ], "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "D2", "movies" : [ "Movie C" ], "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "D3", "movies" : [ "Movie D", "Movie E" ], "count" : 2 }
found 3
{ "nMatched" : 2, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 2 }
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "title" : "Movie A",
    "year" : 2010,
    "director" : "D1",
    "actors" : [
        "A1",
        "A2"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "title" : "Movie B",
    "year" : 2010,
    "director" : "D1",
    "actors" : [
        "A1",
        "A5",
        "A6"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "title" : "Movie C",
    "year" : 2010,
    "director" : "D2",
    "actors" : [
        "A4"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "title" : "Movie D",
    "year" : 2012,
    "director" : "T. Burton",
    "actors" : [
        "A7"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "title" : "Movie E",
    "year" : 2015,
    "director" : "T. Burton",
    "actors" : [
        "A7"
    ]
}
```

The `$match` stage will work on arrays as if they were scalars.  For example, to find all movies in which actor A1 or A4 appears:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: {"actors": {$in: ["A1","A4"]}  }}
]);
```

A simple `$lookup` example:

```
db.foo2.insert([
                {_id:0, location: "Spain"},
                {_id:1, location: "Italy"},
                {_id:2, location: "Italy"},
                {_id:3, location: "USA"},
                {_id:4, location: "Sweden"},
                ]);


c = db.foo2.aggregate([
{$match: {"location": "Italy"}}
,{$lookup: {from: "foo", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "X"}}

// Lookup can produce a one-to-many relationship; thus, "X" will come back                                 
// as an array.   Since we know that the _id-to-_id relationship is 1:1, we                                
// can just grab the first element of X and reset X to be that.  In this                                   
// case, $addFields acts like an assignment expression "x = x + 1" where                                   
// x is overwritten by a new x.                                                                            
,{$addFields: {X: {$arrayElemAt:["$X",0]} }}

// At this point, if you really want, you can $project just the title and                                  
// location or whatever you want.  Sometimes it is more flexible just to                                   
// return the whole shape.  Comment out the next line as an experiment:                                    
,{$project: {_id:true, location:true, title: "$X.title"}}

]);
```

yields:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "location" : "Italy", "title" : "Movie B" }
{ "_id" : 2, "location" : "Italy", "title" : "Movie C" }
```

Comment: I understood very well. Thank you @BuzzMoschetti . That wasn't as scary as I thought. Now, I can practice more on these. What if I were to get all movie titles from collection videoMovie(there are only "_id" field and "title" field) that were recorded in Italy from collection videoMovieDetails? In this case, I have two different collections. It looks like possible with lookup function, am I right?

Comment: @Metalian Answer expanded to include `$lookup`.  Don't be shy to hit up arrow to give it a +1.

Comment: db.video_movie.aggregate([{$match: {"countries": "Italy"}},{$lookup: {from: "video_movieDetails", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "X"}},{$addFields: {X: {$arrayElemAt:["$X",0]} }},{$project: {_id:false, countries:true, title: "$X.title"}}])  doesn't return anything @buzz

Comment: @Metalian  I think your agg/lookup is backwards.   Try `db.video_movieDetails.aggregate()` and change `from` in `$lookup` to `video_movie`.   Look at my example above and ensure your details vs. "main" collection are similar.

Comment: Yes, that was causing the issue. However the return is weird. I'm having:-- { "_id" : ObjectId("5692a31b24de1e0ce2dfd885"), "countries" : [ "Italy", "France" ] }-- not giving me the titles which should give normally. @buzz